# What is the order of a sum of arbitrary positive integers?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity, matching-theory

I am preparing a presentation about a version of Edmond's Blossom Algorithm as it has been
described by William Pulleyblank. The algorithm finds a maximum weight
*b*-matching for a graph $G = (V, E)$ with $n = |V|$ and $b \in \mathbb{N}^n$. The
running time of the algorithm is in $\mathcal{O}(b(V)n^2)$ where $b(V) =
\sum_{v_i \in V}b_i$. So $b$ is a vector of length $n$ of arbitrary positive
integers and the running time of the algorithm depends on the sum over the
entries of $b$.

Now my question is: what is the order of $b(V)$? I would say it's in
$\mathcal{O}(Bn)$ where $B = max\{b_i: v_i \in V\}$. But $B$ can get arbitrarily
large. Could this algorithm then be said to run in polynomial time? If not, what is the bound then?

In general I don't quite understand how an algorithm whose running time depends on more than one variable can be said to have a polynomial running time. I would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: You are right, without further definition it's not clear what polynomial running time means. But you can say, for instance, that it's polynomial in $n$ and $b(V)$.